# Emacs Org-Mode: How to find all TODOs that don't have a deadline specified

Tags: search, emacs, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode I know that I can call up the agenda "match" view (using `C-a m`) and then use the following search string to find all TODO items that have their deadline set to today:

```
DEADLINE="<today>"
```

However, I want to find all items in my TODO list that don't have *any* deadline set at all. I've searched but can't seem to find an answer; the following doesn't seem to work either:

```
DEADLINE=""
```

How do I search for all TODOs that don't have a DEADLINE specified?

(The same also applies to finding items that haven't been scheduled, but I'm guessing the solution will be the same.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

> -DEADLINE={.+}

and

> -SCHEDULED={.+}

which searches for items that don't have a DEADLINE/SCHEDULED tag with any content in it -- ie, no scheduled or deadline dates are set. The curlies are used to identify a regular expression (that matches anything longer than the empty string in this case).

For example, I use the following:

```
 (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
       `(;; match those tagged with :inbox:, are not scheduled, are not DONE.
         ("ii" "[i]nbox tagged unscheduled tasks" tags "+inbox-SCHEDULED={.+}/!+TODO|+STARTED|+WAITING")))
```

Reference: http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html

Comment: Actually is not what is wanted as it will match any headlines without DEADLINE. What is wanted though is to match action items in an open state without DEADLINE

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `org-agenda-skip-entry`. Where I skip the tasks that are scheduled or with a deadline or timestamp and also those that contain the word/tag "desparche".

```
("X" "Not scheduled"
     ( (todo "TODO"
             (
              (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled 'deadline 'timestamp 'regexp "desparche"                                                               ))
              )
             )
       )
     )
```